# USB device numbers overflow behavior

Tags: linux, debian, usb, udev

I have a USB device connected. Each time I send “power on” command over the USB interface, the device disappears from Linux, and reappears as the next device ID.

E.g. if I detected the device as `/dev/bus/usb/001/004` in powered off state, I power it on, it reappears as `/dev/bus/usb/001/005`

Q1. Any idea why Linux increments the device ID instead of reusing? Maybe there’s a setting somewhere that makes device names stable unless user unplugs/replugs them?

Q2. What gonna happen if users will power cycle that peripheral device 1000 times without rebooting the Linux OS which controlling it? Will it switch to 4-digit IDs, will it wrap to zero or one, or will something fail?

Comment: Q1 My guess is that it's too difficult to make sure nothing (e.g. in userspace) still uses an old ID. So they went for the safe variant. Q2 Good question, I guess one would have to look at kernel source code, or try it out ...